# overloading operator== for an user-defined object

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
struct BoughtItemData
{
    uint64 m_playerGUID;
    uint32 m_itemEntryId;
    time_t m_date;

    BoughtItemData(uint64 playerGUID, uint32 itemEntryId, time_t date) : m_playerGUID(playerGUID), m_itemEntryId(itemEntryId), m_date(date) { }
    BoughtItemData(uint64 playerGUID) : m_playerGUID(playerGUID), m_itemEntryId(0), m_date(0) { }

    bool operator==(const BoughtItemData& other) const
    {
        return m_playerGUID == other.m_playerGUID;
    }
};

typedef std::list<BoughtItemData*> ShoppingCart;
```

Somewhere else I need to use `std::find`on ShoppingCart so I'm using this code:

```
const BoughtItemData current(player->GetGUID());

ShoppingCart::const_iterator itr = std::find(cart.begin(), cart.end(), current);
if (itr != cart.end())
//we have found something
```

I'm using `cart.push_back(new BoughtItemData(...))` to add new items to the list.

The error (binary '==' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const BoughtItemData' (or there is no acceptable conversion)) comes from the `std::find` line, I know it isn't done right but I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: It generally helps if you add your error as well...

Comment: I think both answers already point out the mismatch between BoughItemData and BoughtItemData*

Comment: I got that, I'm trying to figure out whether to continue storing pointers or not

Comment: Why would you use pointers? The only thing you should be aware of is that a compiler generated copy constructor, which will be invoked in the push_back, will copy the class on value, so if you have any dynamic allocations there, you should take care of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your list is storing pointers to `BoughtItemData`, but you are searching for a `BoughtItemData` object. A solution would be to store objects in the list:

```
typedef std::list<BoughtItemData> ShoppingCart;
```

You should also think carefully whether you need an `std::list` rather than an `std::vector`.

---

If you really need to store pointers (I seriously doubt you do), then you will have to provide a comparison functor and pass that to `std::find_if`. For example

```
auto cmp = [&current](const BoughtItemData* o)
           {
             return current.m_playerGUID == o->m_playerGUID;
           }

ShoppingCart::const_iterator itr = std::find_if(cart.begin(), cart.end(), cmp);
```

Comment: Yes I realized that but I just don't really know how to search for pointers to BoughtItemData and then implement the operator accordingly. Also, after the search I need to erase that element (which may or may not be at the end of the container) so that's why I chose `std::list`

Comment: @TedyS. Well, I suggested not storing pointers, that would solve the problem. But I added an example with pointers. What you mention is not necessarily a good reason to use `std::list`. In fact, there hardly ever is a good reason to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the example. What I'm trying to accomplish here is to have a link between a player (identified by his playerGUID), the item that he wants to buy (identified by itemEntryId) and the exact time when this happens. The player needs to confirm his purchase so that's why I store that piece of information (which needs to be deleted when he confirms/declines). Do you have a better suggestion on how I can handle all of this?

Comment: @TedyS. Well, I would start by following the suggestion in the first part of the answer. I don't really see the problem with doing that.

Comment: Wouldn't the container become too heavy then?

Comment: @TedyS. No, and you may see better performance from having the data in a contiguous block rather than scattered in memory (another reason to prefer `std::vector` over `std::list`. In any case that is the kind of thing you should determine by profiling different implementations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental flaw in your design. You are storing pointers to your object, which is fine, but could be avoided. Then you define a new `BoughItemData` with name `current`, which you use for your search. The address of `current` will of course never occur in your list of pointers.

You could consider using a `std::map` and search on a key, for instance, if your item is a complex type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have overload the equality comparison operator. That means code like this will work:

```
BoughtItemData a,b;
bool is_equal = a == b;
```

However, that is not what your compile error is complaining about. Your list contains a pointers, not the objects themselves. Now, when you're iterating through it using std::find, you're essentially trying to execute code like this:

```
BoughtItemData current;
BoughtItemData* element_in_list;
bool is_equal = current == element_in_list;
```

Do you see the problem now? The compiler needs a comparison operator that compares a pointer to an object (lets forget about const or not for now) and the only operator it has is one that compares one object to another.

So, how do you solve this problem?
You have three main options:

1. Provide a comparison operator that will work with pointers (this is like a band-aid)
2. Change the list to hold items of type BoughtItemData instead of pointers to it
3. Use smart pointers

The important thing when you choose what to do, is to know why.

Why are you using pointers in the first place? Probably because you don't want to store duplicates. So you need to ask yourself if that list is the only place you're going to be storing BoughtItemData objects? If so, then its perfectly fine to just store the objects themselves in the list.

If you have several data structures that reference the same object, then you do need pointers. However, don't use raw pointers, use smart pointers, the most ubiquitous of which is the [shared pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). A shared pointer will help remove a lot of the burden of the lifetime management associated with containers of pointers.

Even if you did use shared pointers, you would still have to provide a custom function that checked for the equality of the underlying objects, because STL containers will still only compare the pointer values.

So really, the best solution to your problem depends on the way you've designed your application. But there is one piece of advice I can give you: **when you have the option of multiple solutions that seem equally good, always choose the simplest**. This will make your code easier to read, understand and maintain in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I changed the list to a vector and it now stores objects, not pointers. This was my first idea as well, but for some reason I thought that handling pointers instead of objects can save me from stack overflow (I probably just need to get a better grasp of memory management in C++). Thanks again.